# Finding the distribution function of a continuous random variable with a density function including a minimum

Tags: probability-distributions

I have been scratching my head about this question for a long time.
I found one other question on here that included a minimum function for probability functions but unfortunately there wasn't enough information to make me understand this enough to proceed.

The question states:

Let X is a continuous random variable with probability density function

$$f(x) = c \min \left( 1, \dfrac 1 {x^4} \right)$$

(a) Find c and the (cumulative) distribution function of X.

(b) Find EX, VarX, and the median of X.

Based on the example I saw, this gave me a density function:

$$f(x) = \begin{cases}
c & \mbox{for } -1 ≤ x ≤ 1\\
\tfrac{c}{x^4} & \mbox{for } |x| > 1\end{cases}$$

Is this correct?
If so then by setting the summation of the integrals of these f(x) cases gives me a value of 3/8 for c.

And if so would I be correct to get a distribution function as:

$$F(x) = \begin{cases} \int_{1}^{\infty} \tfrac{3}{8x^4} dx & \text{if } x>1 \\ \int_{-1}^{1} \tfrac{3}{8} dx & \text{if } -1 ≤ x ≤ 1 \\ \int_{-\infty}^{-1} \tfrac{3}{8x^4} & \text{if } x < -1\end{cases}$$

I'm not sure about this though and even if this is correct, I'm not sure how to use this for part b.

Comment: Have you noticed that, with your definition, $F(x)$ is piecewise constant?

Comment: I feel like the problem for me lies with my original definition for f(x). It is the min part of the function that has me confused.

Comment: Your alternative definition of $f$ is correct. :)

Comment: so this one is correct?: $$f(x) = \begin{cases}
c & \mbox{for } -1 ≤ x ≤ 1\\
\tfrac{c}{x^4} & \mbox{for } |x| > 1\end{cases}$$

Comment: yes, that definition is correct.

Comment: I'm unsure on how to calculate the EX, VarX and median based on this type of distribution function. I've mostly worked on discrete random variables before this question and so this is taking a while to get used to. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Better to write a separate question for this. :)

Answer (score 0):

By definition,

$$F(x) = \int_{-\infty}^x f(y) \,  dy, $$

so we obtain:

$$F(x) = \begin{cases} 
\int_{-\infty}^{x} \tfrac{3}{8y^4} dy = \frac{1}{8} \, |x|^{-3}& \text{if } x < -1\\ 
F(-1) + \int_{-1}^{x} \tfrac{3}{8} dy = \frac{1}{8} (4 + 3x) & \text{if } -1 ≤ x ≤ 1 \\ 
F(1) + \int_{1}^{x} \tfrac{3}{8y^4}dx = 1 - \frac{1}{8} |x|^{-3} & \text{if } x>1 \end{cases}
$$

Comment: Ah I see, so I missed out the F(1) and F(-1)